# Android:TextToSpeech Not Working

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, text-to-speech

Hi i create one application which is depend on TextToSpeech. When i am trying to run my
application It show the NullPointerException in Logcat. i search lot but didn't find    helpful Answer.Here [Check my Code on this link](http://pastebin.com/KmKk0XiV) and Here is my logcat.

```
04-10 15:11:37.872: WARN/System.err(2798): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 15:11:37.872: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.example.examguide.ExamAppearingActivity.onCreate(ExamAppearingActivity.java:80)
04-10 15:11:37.872: WARN/System.err(2798):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-10 15:11:37.882: WARN/System.err(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-10 15:11:37.882: WARN/System.err(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-10 15:11:37.882: WARN/System.err(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-10 15:11:37.882: WARN/System.err(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-10 15:11:37.882: WARN/System.err(2798):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 15:11:37.882: WARN/System.err(2798):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 15:11:37.882: WARN/System.err(2798):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-10 15:11:37.882: WARN/System.err(2798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 15:11:37.892: WARN/System.err(2798):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 15:11:37.892: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-10 15:11:37.892: WARN/System.err(2798):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-10 15:11:37.892: WARN/System.err(2798):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help is Appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

you have used this code.

```
final List<ObjectiveWiseQuestion> QuestionWiseProfile1= db.getOneQuestion(examId);
```

but you have not opened db before. So it is getting null.
ok write

```
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
```

before you use tts object.

Comment: actually when i compile it,db.getOneQuestion fetch all value but when it come on tts.speak(question, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null); it hit error

Comment: can i use tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this); before list<objectivewisequestion> profile=db.getOneQuestion(examId)

Answer (score 1):

The tts object is not initialized. Hence you get a null pointer exception there.

Comment: Just initialize like tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this); provided your activity implements OnInitListener